# OpenLayers3 create icon and zoom to it

Tags: icons, openlayers-3

I have a function that creates new layer with one point, which has icon to be shown on the map. When created I want map to zoom and to set center on that point. 
The problem is the icon is shown only when I pan or zoom map a little bit (after it was created and map centered). If remove zooming and panning, icon appears on the map perfectly. But when I set center, icon is not visible.
Here you can see it> http://jsfiddle.net/anuket/1orw65g9/4/

```
function createIcon(){
        var newFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(["536433.08", "6586576.42"])
        });
        var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                anchor: [0.5, 46],
                anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                opacity: 0.75,
                src: 'http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/data/icon.png'
            }))
        });
        var VectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({

        });
        VectorSource.addFeature(newFeature);
        var VectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: VectorSource,
            style: iconStyle
        });
        map.addLayer(VectorLayer);
        var coordinates = newFeature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        map.getView().setCenter(coordinates);
        map.getView().setZoom(2);
    }
```

Comment: And even if I first zoom and set center and then create new layer with icon, I is not seen until I zoom in/out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coordinate values need to be numbers, not strings. Remove the quotes:

```
geometry: new ol.geom.Point([536433.08, 6586576.42])
```